# Django Not Found: /virtual/Scripts/dashApp/static/main.css

Tags: python, django

I have looked through SO and this seems to be a common issue among new django users however none of what I have attempted has fixed my issue.

after running dev server `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` I get not found error in `CMD` window

`Not Found: /virtual/Scripts/dashApp/static/main.css`

`Not Found: /virtual/Scripts/dashApp/static/main.js`

the relevant `html` in my app as below

`<link href= virtual/Scripts/dashApp/static/main.css rel="stylesheet"></head>`

`<script type="text/javascript" src= virtual/Scripts/dashApp/static/main.js ></script>`

both the `.css` and `.js` file live in

`C:\Users\James\Desktop\Scripts\django\dealerDash\virtual\Scripts\dashApp\static`

my `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [    
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR , 'static')
```

I have tried wrapping `virtual/Scripts/dashApp/static/main.css`  as `"virtual/Scripts/dashApp/static/main.css "` and `/virtual/Scripts/dashApp/static/main.css`  but without joy..

Comment: you can't directly give a path into HTML file. write src="{% static 'main.js' %}" insead of "virtual/Scripts/dashApp/static/main.js"

Comment: thanks, this then give `Invalid block tag on line 1366: 'static'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`

Comment: actually, i need to add `{% load static %}`.. working now.. thank you

Comment: if you used {% extend 'file.html' %} then add {% load static %} after this tag, if not used this, then add on the first line of HTML page.